# SQL simple rounding

Tags: sql-server, rounding

Query:

```
declare @a float(10);
declare @b float(10);
declare @c float(10);
set @a = 150.50;
set @b = 19;
set @c = 100;
select @a * @b / @c as result
,ROUND(@a * @b / @c, 2) as rounded
```

Resulting in:

```
| result  | rounded  |    
----------------------
| 28.595  | 28.59    |
```

Should the rounded be 28.60? How do I achieve this?

Comment: you wanted to round 2 decimal places, the result is correct

Comment: Could you clarify, what you want exactly   because  28.60 equals to 28.6 and If you want to obtain this result you can use ROUND(@a * @b / @c, 1)

Comment: I need two decimal places, result should be 28.60

Comment: @Squirrel No, this result is not correct. Both for numerical and banker rounding result should be 28.60.

Comment: You choose bad example - use set @b = 27 for example :)

Answer (score 1):

You say:

`I need two decimal places, result should be 28.60`

This sentence is somewhat ambiguous. Thankfully, the number you provide clarifies the case:

1. You want to round to *ONE* decimal place. This is done by changing the second parameter of the `ROUND` function:
   `ROUND(@a * @b / @c, 1) as rounded`
   But, also...
2. You want to *DISPLAY* two decimal digits. That does not have to do with the `ROUND` function, but with formatting functions. One trick is to convert to a decimal type with exactly the amount of decimals you want:
   `convert(decimal(10,2),ROUND(@a * @b / @c, 1)) as rounded`

Comment: Problem is not in rounding, but in float datatype. There is nothing ambiguous in OP sentence - 28.60 has two decimal places. 28.6 would have one, but OP doesn't want that.

Comment: @Arvo It is not defined whether the need of two decimal places refers to the rounding accuracy or the display digit count.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following code

```
declare @a float(10);
declare @b float(10);
declare @c float(10);
set @a = 150.50;
set @b = 19;
set @c = 100;
select @a * @b / @c as result
,FORMAT(ROUND(@a * @b / @c, 1),'N') as rounded
```

and result set will be;

```
+--------+---------+
| result | rounded |
+--------+---------+
| 28.595 |   28.60 |
+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Set @b = 27 and you see, where you fail.

Comment: In the question,  the 28.595 number wanted to round 28.60. If we set the @b  as variable  27 the result will be 40.635 and it will be rounded to 40.60. There is no difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in the @b = 27 case OP would want 40.64 :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use float, but some exact dataype, like decimal():

```
declare @a decimal(19,5);
declare @b decimal(19,5);
declare @c decimal(19,5);
set @a = 150.50;
set @b = 19;
set @c = 100;
select @a * @b / @c as result
,ROUND(@a * @b / @c, 2) as rounded
```

which results

```
result  rounded
28.595000   28.600000
```

Comment: a, b and c are system-rows and I can´t change them. I´ve tried cast(...) as decimal(19,5) inside select statement but with no luck.

Comment: @user2463808 cast columns separately, before calculating. Your result (28.595) as float is internally 28.594999999999999 (float is inexact!!!) and that rounds to 28.59.

Comment: then I could theoreticly do something like "select ROUND(ROUND(28.594999999999999, 3), 2)" but it does not work in my example

Comment: @user2463808 No, you cannot - unless converted to decimal() in some stage, every round internally keeps this ...999... part. Read somewhere about float datatype internals - this is too long story to explain here in comments. Just remember - float numbers are not exact. Oh, and you should never use round() inside round() - this can give wrong results even using exact numbers - round(round(0.4445, 3), 2) = 0.45, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a decimal(9, 2);
declare @b decimal(9, 2);
declare @c decimal(9, 2);

set @a = 150.50
set @b = 19
set @c = 100

select @a * @b / @c as result
,CAST(ROUND(@a * @b / @c, 2) as decimal(9,2)) as rounded
```